# AppleScript: Triggering input file with .click() doesn't actually attaches a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, applescript

What I have in here is a page manipulation through Safari using Javascript.

```
set eshopwedropUrlDialog to display dialog "Eshopwedrop Item URL" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
set eshopwedropPriceDialog to display dialog "Price" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"

set eshopwedropUrl to text returned of eshopwedropUrlDialog
set eshopwedropPrice to text returned of eshopwedropPriceDialog

tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:eshopwedropUrl}
    activate
    set jq to do shell script "curl https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    do JavaScript "$('.customs-banner').hide();" in document 1
    do JavaScript "$('#dg_no').click();" in document 1
    do JavaScript "$('#address_id').val('23118').change()" in document 1
    do JavaScript "$('#prices_0_price').val('" & eshopwedropPrice & "')" in document 1
    do JavaScript "$('#lion_upload_btn').click()" in document 1
end tell/

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
    delay 1
    keystroke "~/Downloads/ebay.png"
    delay 1
    keystroke return
    
end tell
```

This particular line `do JavaScript "$('#lion_upload_btn').click()" in document 1` doesn't work well. It does opens Finder window and picks up a file, but within the web page no file is attached. I think this might be due some custom handler used within jQuery code on that web.

As this page requires login I'm providing a gist [link](https://gist.github.com/holms/e3b93b628c73f4e7b069936591b6326e) to the source. In a file `functions.js` SimpleUploader library is used. I can't find the trigger anywhere, not even sure how to debug it. I think there should be some kind of a handler which takes control of `click()` event, does some logic before file is even picked, and does some logic after file is picked (because it shows file list when they are attached). I believe I need to call that particular handler in order to have correct file attachment.

Comment: I have a very similar code to yours, could you try adding another `delay 1` and `keystroke return` to your last tell block, right after keystroke return, and see if that works? Also, instead of using javascript to click the upload button, treat the button as UI button and click it as such. In my case I used something like `click button "no file selected" of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window APP_NAME`

Comment: Interesting, I'll try. I didn't go this way because finding an element with such strange syntax is pain, I though just using selector is ok. But probably this might solve the issue indeed

Comment: @user3579815 could you please explain what is that "no file selected", i have no such button anywhere, also as how do you know number of group and scroll area.. and what window name should be?

Comment: The button "no file selected" is the UI component from the webpage I was working with, that was identified by the tool I used, `UI Browser`. I reckon it would be similar if I used Accessibility Inspector that comes with XCode.